# AngularJS - Spring POST request with check boxes

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm currently learning AngularJS with Sprint Boot and using the POST request. I know the back end is working correctly, however, I'm trying to figure what might be the issue with using checkboxes and Spring Boot MVC. Forgive if my code is bad, still new.

Error message:

```
{
 "status" : "400",
 "cause" : null,
 "method" : "POST",
 "message" : "Required request body is missing: public void com.velatt.dartentitlements.api.SiteController.addServicesToSite(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<com.velatt.dartentitlements.domain.DeService>) throws java.net.URISyntaxException",
 "exception" : "HttpMessageNotReadableException",
 "path" : "/sites/1/services",
 "error" : "Bad Request"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

angularJs

```
// create array to hold request data
var selectedObjArray = [];

// push data to array.
 selectedObjArray.push(....);


$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/sites/" + $scope.targetEntity.siteId + "/services",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},   // change content type to json
        data:selectedObjArray ,
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.services = response.data;
    });
```

Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sites/{id}/services", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
public void addServicesToSite(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody List<DeService> incoming) throws URISyntaxException {
    for (Link link : incoming.getLinks()) {
        DeService deService = utilityService.getDomainObjectFromUriString(link.getHref(), DeService.class);
        service.addServiceToSite(id, deService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass body from you ajax like following:

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/sites/" + $scope.targetEntity.siteId + "/services",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data:addRequest,
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.services = response.data;
        });
```